# Browser history doesn't work as expected with drupal panes

Tags: url, drupal, browser-history, panels, panes

I have a drupal site developed with panels, and I have a panel with different panes with visibility rules set by url string, and the browser history doesn't work as spected, What could be possible reasons?

Comment: what do the urls look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching within project templates, I figured out that I have data-href instead normal anchors and these not push href to browser history.